# Query (in CSWP) to match keyid column from from two site collections

Tags: crawled-property

I have a question on SharePoint 2013 `content search web part`.

I have two `document libraries` in two `separate site collections`. Both document lib have common `column` name `KeyID`.

I am trying to get all document lib items when there has match. KeyID is also managed property in both site collections.

What could be the KQL query on Content search web part?

```
{searchTerms} (path:"https://sitecollection1/DistrictDocuments1"
```

KeyIDOWSTEXT:any value   returns items from lib 1

```
{searchTerms} (path:"https://sitecollection2/DistrictDocuments2")
```

KeyIDOWSTEXT:any value   returns items from lib 2

Looking for a query which will match lib1  with    lib2   using KeyIDOWSTEXT Managed Property.

Comment: Are your site collections in 2 different Web Applications? Or in same?

Comment: Both site collections are in the same web application. thanks, Utpal